# Is the return statement allowed on constexpr constructors?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, c++14, constexpr

As explained in [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), the compound statement of the body of a `constexpr` constructor, if it is not deleted nor defaulted, must satisfy the constraints for the body of a `constexpr` function, that is, it may contain any statements except:

- an `asm` declaration
- a `goto` statement
- a `try`-block
- a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is performed

It seems that the standard does not restrict the number of `return` statements that may appear, whereas, in C++11, only one was allowed.

Now, consider the following code:

```
class Thing
{
    public:
        // Shouldn't this constructor be fine under both C++11 and C++14?
        constexpr Thing ( )
        {
            return;
        }
};

int main ( )
{
    Thing a_nice_thing;
}
```

Clang (3.5 with *-std=c++14*) compiles it fine, but GCC (4.9.1 with *-std=c++14*) does not, complaining:

> constexpr constructor does not have empty body

However, if it is changed:

```
class Thing
{
    public:
        // This constructor is fine under both C++11 and C++14
        constexpr Thing ( )
        {
            static_assert( __cplusplus > 1 , "static_assert isn't the right mechanism to test this, since it wasn't available at earlier versions of the language" );
        }
};

int main ( )
{
    Thing a_nice_thing;
}
```

Then it compiles fine under both compilers.

Since GCC complains about the constructor's body not being empty, shouldn't it also complain in the later case? Is this behavior a bug in GCC? Is the return statement allowed on constexpr constructors?

<sub>Note: whether a single `return` statement is really worth is not the scope of this question, although interesting and perhaps worth another one. I put single `return` statements on constructors whose body is empty, for style reasons.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC currently [doesn't support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) C++14's version of `constexpr`, so even with `-std=c++14` you still get C++11's `constexpr`.

The C++11 restriction on the body of `constexpr` constructors is (§7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr]/p4):

> the *compound-statement* of its *function-body* shall contain only
>
> - null statements,
> - *static_assert-declarations*
> - `typedef` declarations and *alias-declarations* that do not define classes or enumerations,
> - *using-declarations*,
> - and *using-directives*;

(There are lots of other restrictions as well; I limited the quote to the one relevant to the question.)

`return` statements are not allowed in `constexpr` constructors in C++11, while `static_assert`s are.

Comment: Then, the first example is not C++11-compliant. But, why does GCC complain about it, when the C++14 language is enabled?

Comment: @Kalrish Because GCC doesn't currently support C++14 `constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression it did (or mostly did) because of the command line switch.

Answer (score 1):

C++14 it changed,  as covered by the [draft C++14 standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section 7.1.5 The constexpr specifier

> its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or a compound-statement that does not contain
>
> — an asm-definition,
>
> — a goto statement,
>
> — a try-block, or
>
> — a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which
>   no initialization is performed

and a constructor must follow the additional restrictons:

> — either its function-body shall be = default, or the compound-statement of its function-body shall satisfy
>   the constraints for a function-body of a constexpr function;
>
> — every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized (12.6.2);
>
> — if the class is a union having variant members (9.5), exactly one of them shall be initialized;
>
> — if the class is a union-like class, but is not a union, for each of its anonymous union members having
>   variant members, exactly one of them shall be initialized;
>
> — for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and
>   base class sub-objects shall be a constexpr constructor;
>
> — for a delegating constructor, the target constructor shall be a constexpr constructor.

and it does not prevent a *return statement* nor a `static_assert`.

in C++11 it included the restrictions:

> — the compound-statement of its function-body shall contain only
>
> — null statements,
>
> — static_assert-declarations
>
> — typedef declarations and alias-declarations that do not define classes or enumerations,
>
> — using-declarations,
>
> — and using-directives

which does not allow a return statement.